# Does reading / writing to the CloudCode log count against my account's API requests?

Tags: logging, parse-platform

When my CloudCode function outputs something to the log (via `console.log`, or just the built-in logging that Parse does,) does that count against my API request quota?

Similarly, when I'm reading my log with the command line tool or using the logging API directly, does that count against my API quota?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, console logs and looking at your logs do not use up api requests.

source: I work at Parse.